# Are fonts only white and transparent?

Tags: fonts, freetype

I am using Freetype to decode TTF files then render the glyphs onto a texture.
Should all pixels in a character be only white or transparent(255, 255, 255, 255 or 0, 0, 0, 0) or are they able to be gray or translucent(ex 140, 140, 140, 255 or 255, 255, 255, 130)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question doesn't make a lot of sense: an opentype font with ttf outlines gives you the vector *outline* for glyphs, and if there is no explicit colour information inside the font (in the form of a COLR table), there is literally no colour that the pixels of the rasterized vector "should be". Not in terms of colours, and not in terms of alpha blending (antialiasing).

These things are choices that you make, or users of your application make, and are passed to Freetype as instructions on how to go about the rasterizing operation.

Answer (score -1):

On freetype you can use multiple colors you'll just have to know the RGB code for the color

Comment: I don't want to change the color of the characters, I want to know how I should render them onto a texture.